# Volverse vs. ponerse

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, adjetivos

En r/Spanish hicieron [una pregunta sencilla](https://www.reddit.com/r/Spanish/comments/gnf49k/this_is_getting_weird/) con una derivación interesante: ¿cómo es mejor decir, “volverse raro” o “ponerse raro” (hablando de una situación, traduciendo del inglés *“to get weird”*)? A priori me resultó obvio que es “ponerse raro”, aunque la otra opción no sea incorrecta, pero después me puse a pensar si no hay alguna lógica, ya que una persona se **pone** rara o furiosa pero se **vuelve** loca o estúpida, y una situación puede **volverse** extraña, **ponerse** difícil, **volverse** personal y **ponerse** peligrosa. Puede ocurrir que ambos verbos sean admisibles y en tal caso puede ser que el significado difiera sutilmente.

Quisiera saber si existe alguna lógica, más allá de la arbitrariedad y de variaciones dialectales, para la colocación entre *ponerse* vs. *volverse* y diferentes (tipos de) adjetivos. Quisiera evitar anécdotas particulares, pero las teorías personales son bienvenidas.

Answer (score 1):

Las dos principales (aunque sutiles) diferencias podrían ser:

- "volverse" es algo más literario que "ponerse".
- "volverse" suele indicar un proceso más gradual de conversión o transformación que "ponerse" ("ponerse" pareciera indicar el estadio final de la conversión más que el proceso).